# Disable grid panel with checkboxes

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid, fieldset, gridpanel

My requirement is that to disable a grid panel inside field set or grid rows on certain condition. The grid has more than 20 items and there should be a scroll bar to view all the elements of the grid. If I use disabled property of grid panel, then the scroll bar also gets disabled. But i need the scroll bar to be enabled, so that user can see all items of grid.

For above i coded with feildset autoscroll: true and layout:fit. But on disabling the grid panel, the scrollbar of fieldset also gets disabled because of layout:fit property of fieldset. Is there any way to achieve the requirement?

Code:

```
Ext.applyIf(this,  {
    border : false,
    frame : false,
    bodyStyle : 'padding:12px 15px 0px',
    labelAlign : 'top',
    columnWidth : 0.5,
    heigth : 350,
    layout : 'form',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'fields',
        id: 'fields',
        layout: 'fit',
        height: 321,
        autoScroll: true,
        title: 'Element list',
        items: mygridPanel
    }]
})
```

Comment: Did you try wrapping the gridpanel in another panel that has autoscroll, so when you disable the gridpanel the outer panel is still active, so the scrollbar should still function?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried with below code it works in firefox. In ie it throws run time error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made up a small demo on jsFiddle for you to look at:

http://jsfiddle.net/CGtqp/

does this help you solve your issue?